# How to broadcast my matrix exponentiation

Tags: python, scipy, numpy

I'm trying -to no avail- to [broadcast](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) the following piece of code in `Python`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import expm

def ExactSol(c, omega0, x0, v0, T, p):
    # Docstring
    """
    Returns the solution of
    x'' + c x' + w0^2 x = 0
    embodied with initial condition x(0) = x0 and x'(0) = v0
    i.e. the function X(t) = exp(tA) * X0
    with X = (x, v), X0 = (x0, v0), A = (0       1)
                                        (-w0^2  -c)
    over [0,T] cut in p sub-intervals
    Positional arguments:
    c      -- damping parameter
    omega0 -- pulsation
    x0     -- initial position
    v0     -- initial speed
    T      -- final time
    p      -- the number of samples in [0,T]
    Keyword arguments:
    """
    # Body
    time = np.linspace(0, T, p + 1)
    time = time[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
    X0   = np.array([x0, v0])
    A    = np.array([[0, 1], [- omega0**2, - c]])
    B    = time * A
    E    = np.zeros(B.shape)
    for i in range(0, B.shape[0]):
        E[i,:,:] = expm(B[i,:,:])
    return time[:,0,0], E@X0
```

I would like to avoid the use of a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ is only a 2x2 matrix, you could just hard-code the matrix exponentiation. Note that if we can write $A=UDU^{-1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues of $A$ and the columns of $U$ are the associated eigenvectors, then $e^A = Ue^DU^{-1}$ and $e^{tA} = Ue^{tD}U^{-1}$, where $t$ is a scalar.

All that remains is to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. It's a little ugly, but it's probably faster than your code. Based on [this](http://matriisi.ee.tut.fi/~piche/ode/expm2/). Note that I didn't address the case of a defective matrix.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig,inv

def ExactSol(c, omega0, x0, v0, T, p):
    time = np.linspace(0, T, p + 1)
    A = np.array([[0, 1], [- omega0**2, - c]])
    e,U = eig(A)
    tol = 1.e-6
    E = np.zeros( (p+1,2,2),dtype=float)
    if abs(e[0]-e[1]) < tol:
        # this is a defective matrix, which must be handled differently
        raise UserWarning("Defective matrix not implemented")
    else:
        # the eigenvalues are distinct -- possibly complex, but 
        # E will always be real
        Uinv=inv(U)
        for k in range(2):
            E += np.real(np.exp(time*e[k])[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis] *
                         np.dot(U[:,k,np.newaxis], Uinv[np.newaxis,k,:])[np.newaxis,:,:] )

    X0 = np.array([x0, v0])
    X = np.dot(E,X0[:,np.newaxis])
    return time, X
```

---

Edit: Some quick timing information. I set `omega0=1.0`, `c=0.1`, `x0=0.0`, `v0=1.0`, `T=100.0`, and `p=10000`. Using your code, this function takes 2.95 seconds, while using my code, it takes 0.0025 seconds on my machine. So I've improved efficiency by a factor of over 1000.

Comment: $A$ is 2*2 in this MWE, but could be bigger. Also I see a for loop in your proposal, which defeats the purpose of the question.

Comment: @bela83 You didn't specify that $A$ could be larger, but the general premise here will extend to higher orders. Obviously, I could "unroll" that for loop. So you don't want _any_ for loops?? This isn't code golf. I assumed that you wanted to avoid the for loop over time steps, because there is typically a lot of them, and the expm() function might be expensive. While there might be some crazy Python indexing that can be used to avoid this for loop, why is it necessary?

Comment: You are right that I didn't specify that $A$ could be larger. I thought, as a rule of thumb, that the use of for loops should be avoided when using ndarrays. I wonder if my approach can be tackled without the loop, using the ndarray broadcasting machinery, which I don't master at all.

Comment: IMO, for loops are not necessarily a bad thing. What's important is efficiency and readability. In your case, your efficiency is bad because the costly expm() function is in a for loop which will be iterated thousands of times. In my case, the number of iterations is small, so there's no problem. I doubt there's a way to do this your way, since the expm() function doesn't support broadcast operations. It's an expensive operation even it was vectorized. (Note: I edited the answer with timing information.)

Comment: thank you for your edit. You are right, and I acknowledge the massive improve in efficiency. I'm just still wondering if another option would be possible...

Comment: Your exponentiation function can probably be broadcasted using `np.einsum` over arbitrary  dimensions to prevent the `for` loop.  Your real problem will probably be the inversion of `U` as your dimensionality increases.